# Should I delete a question when the problem was in the documentation?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423819/error-getting-voice-pricing-for-specific-numbers) about an error I was getting while using a particular library, and it turned out the problem was actually with the library's documentation, and not with my code.

Should I delete my question:

1. As soon as I find out the error is a documentation issue?
2. Once the online documentation is corrected?
3. Never, and just leave it for the historical record?

Comment: Personally, and I would wait for a few more opinions before you act, I would leave the question up until the documentation is correct. However! You cannot delete the question if the answer has upvotes or it has more than one answer. So by the time the documentation is updated (if they haven't already) it'll often be the case that you just can't delete, at least by yourself.

Comment: @Kendra Why not make this an answer?

Comment: I feel at this point it's pretty well covered by the other answers. Originally, I just posted a comment as that was what I would do but I didn't know if it was the recommended way. I looks like leaving it up is more accepted. :)

Comment: Keep it till there's no reason to think anyone would be working off the old, erroneous documentation anymore -- at a minimum, five to ten years after the documentation is corrected.  However, as soon as the documentation *is* corrected, edit the answer to record the date and version(s) in which that happened.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to delete the question.

Someone else may have run into a similar problem, used the buggy code (as Servy suggests), or still be working off a copy of the documentation that has the problem. You never know.

We have millions of garbage questions on SO - leaving one up that might still be useful (even though it's not certain) won't hurt anybody.

And even if the question may no longer be relevant, there is no reason to take away the reputation points from the answerer - especially given that they're actually from Twilio itself!

Comment: Yes - documentation problems are oten more insidious than 'normal' bugs:(

Answer (score 20):

The fact that there is buggy code in the documentation would make it all the more important to have an SO question about it.  If anything it would increase its value.

After the documentation is fixed, presumably it's still a sensible question, as it's a problem someone else could have in their own code, even if the problem didn't come from copy-pasting the bug from the docs.  Of course, the answer should really explain what the bug is, why it's happening, and how to fix it, not just say that the bug is in the docs, so that it will actually be useful to future visitors once the docs are fixed.